# Recursive Read of Files, Copy Section and Append to New File?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to iterate through a couple of directories to read all the corresponding files and copy a section of text from the file and append to a new separate file.

The Text is located between,

```
"<!-- Begin .post -->"
<h2 class="post-title">licenses new Internet</h2>
<h3 class="date-header">Thursday, 21 January 2017</h3>
<div class="post-body" style="text-align:justify;">

. . .

</div>
<div class="post-footer">
     <em>posted by Me</em>
</div>
"<!-- End .post -->"
```

What would be the best method please?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do all the files are HTML files ? Which text do you want to get ? It's inside a HTML tag ?

Comment: yes, all HTML-based files with the extension of .php. I require all the HTML from inside the "Begin .post" to "End .post" section.

Comment: Can you post a full example page ?

Comment: In this case, you have two ways to do this, as you want to get the content between the HTML comment tag, you would parse it using a regular expression to match your needs, if you could get data of a parent node, you should use the PHP DOM class (http://php.net/DOM). Both methods works, but I believe that the DOM method has a better performance and it's more accurate.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That does sound a bit beyond me.

Comment: I created a Cut function with start and finish needles. Thank you Lucas Mednes for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function copySection($sStartNeedle, $sEndNeedle, $sText)
{
    $sText = substr($sText, strpos($sText, $sStartNeedle) + strlen($sStartNeedle));
    $sText = substr($sText, 0, strpos($sText, $sEndNeedle));

    return( $sText );
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15638500)

Comment: Thank you @MichelGokan for your advice. The essential part is the function to retrieve the block of code. The recursive search of directories has been dealt with many times. As this code is part of a conversion tool, the PHP tool has been removed as it's a one-off operation, i.e. no link.